# Live Search Component

Tags: vue.js, filtering

I am fetching my data from external API link and I would like to filter them - live searching, so when I type a letter, the results that includes that letter will get filtered.

For now I am not able to do it and when I click into my input I just get all the results printed out and nothing is happening when I am trying to filter them.

This is my logic in script:

```
data() {
    return {
      result: "",
      modal: false,
      results: [],
      filteredResults: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("secretDataURL")
      .then((response) => {
        this.filteredResults = response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => (this.filteredResults = console.log(error)))
      .finally(() => console.log("Data successfully loaded"));
  },
  methods: {
    filterResults() {
      if (this.result.lenght == 0) {
        this.filteredResults = this.results;
      }
      this.filteredResults = this.results.filter((result) => {
        return result.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.result.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
    setResult(result) {
      this.result = result;
      this.modal = false;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    state() {
      this.filterResults();
    },
  }
```

And my template

```
<div @click="modal = false"></div>
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="result"
      autocomplete="off"
      @input="filterResults"
      @focus="modal = true"
    />
    <div v-if="filteredResults && modal">
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="(filteredResult, index) in filteredResults"
          :key="index"
          @click="setResult(filteredResult)"
        >
          {{ filteredResult.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

How can I make it work, where my logic is failing ?

Comment: I don't think this is the issue but you have a typo `if (this.result.lenght == 0) {`. Most IDEs should catch these.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my typo, but yeah, that is not the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

U get the data in hook `mounted`.
And then lost it.

[image]

---

Change `this.filteredResults = response.data;` to `this.results = response.data;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not sure I understand though, can you explain what do you mean by i "lost it" ?

Comment: got it! change `this.filteredResults = response.data;` to `this.results = response.data;`

Comment: Hmm I think I got your logic now, but unfortunately it does not work - i am getting an error result.toLowerCase is not a function